# Random Hex Color Generator + RGB Sliders jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm having issues getting this hex randomizer function to pass the value (var hex) to generate a new color. I'm not good with event handlers yet so any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

```
<body>
 <div id="backgroundColor" style="background:#EEE8CD;">
   <p>R:
     <span class="wrap_red"><input class="r ch" type="range" min="0" max="255" /></span>
     <input type="number" min="0" max="255" />
   </p>
   <p>G:
     <span class="wrap_green"><input class="g ch" type="range" min="0" max="255" /></span>
     <input type="number" min="0" max="255" />
   </p>
   <p>B:   
     <span class="wrap_blue"><input class="b ch" type="range" min="0" max="255" /></span>
     <input type="number" min="0" max="255" />
   </p>
   <table id="tableRGB">
     <tr>
         <td>
           <strong>RGB: </strong>#<span class="result">567890</span>
         </td>
         <td>
           <strong> Hexadecimal: </strong>#<input type="number">
         </td>
    </tr>  
    </table> 
   <button type="button" id="button" onclick="click();">Generate</button>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    var Color = {
    defaults: {
    // Predefined hex codes that cant be used as random colors
    // All must be prefixed with the '#' indicator
    predef: [],

    // Maximum & Minimum random range values
    rangeMax: 255,
    rangeMin: 0,

    // Upper and lower level values that must be 
    // passed for random color acceptance
    //
    // By setting levelUp: 200, levelDown: 100; Neutral
    // colors like White, Gray, and Black can be somewhat weeded
    // out and your random colors will be full spectrum based.
    // Note*: Doing so increases likely hood of recursion
    levelUp: -1,
    levelDown: 256,

    // Recursion handlers
    recursionLimit: 15,
    recursion: function () {
        throw 'Recursion Error in Random Color Generator, ' +
            'too many tries on finding random color, ' +
            '[Limit ' + this.recursionLimit + ']';
    }
},

// Caching of random colors
stack: {},

// Returns a random color in hex code form, and caches
// find in the stack.

rand: function () {
    var defaults = this.defaults;
    return defaults.rangeMin + Math.floor(Math.random()*(defaults.rangeMax+1));
},
random: function (i) {
    var self = this,
        defaults = self.defaults,
        r = self.rand(),
        g = self.rand(),
        b = self.rand(),
        hex = self.rgb2hex(r, g, b),
        levels = true;

    // Check for recursion
    if (i === undefined || typeof i !== 'number') i = 0;
    else if (i++ > defaults.recursionLimit) return defaults.recursion();

    // Color already used, try another one
    if (self.stack[hex]) hex = self.random(i);

    // Ensure one of the vals is above levelUp and another is below levelDown
    // Check defaults comments for better understanding
    levels = !!(
        (r > defaults.levelUp || g > defaults.levelUp || b > defaults.levelUp) &&
        (r < defaults.levelDown || g < defaults.levelDown || b < defaults.levelDown)
    );
    if (! levels) hex = self.random(i);

    // Store on stack to help prevent repeat
    self.stack[hex] = [r,g,b];

    // Return hex code in #
    return hex;
}


// Returns hex code
rgb2hex: function (r,g,b) {
    var str = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    return '#' + [
        str.charAt( (r - r % 16) / 16) + str.charAt(r % 16),
        str.charAt( (g - g % 16) / 16) + str.charAt(g % 16),
        str.charAt( (b - b % 16) / 16) + str.charAt(b % 16)
    ].join('');
},

// Returns in array form [red, green, blue]
hex2rgb: function (hex) {
    if (hex.substr(0,1) === '#')
        hex = hex.substr(1);

    // Use the stack if possible to reduce processing
    return this.stack['#' + hex] ? this.stack['#' + hex] : 
        hex.length === 6 ? [
            parseInt(hex.substr(0, 2), 16),
            parseInt(hex.substr(2, 2), 16),
            parseInt(hex.substr(4, 2), 16)
        ] : hex.length === 3 ? [
            parseInt(hex.substr(0, 1), 16),
            parseInt(hex.substr(1, 1), 16),
            parseInt(hex.substr(2, 1), 16)
        ] : [];
}
   };
//Random color generator button
$('#generate').click( function () {
    $('div').each(function() {
        var th = $(this);
        hex = th.css('backgroundColor');
        rgb = hex.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
        var red = rgb[1];
        var green = rgb[2];
        var blue = rgb[3];

        th.find('.r').val(red);
        th.find('.r').parent('span').siblings('input').val(red);
        th.find('.g').val(green);
        th.find('.g').parent('span').siblings('input').val(green);
        th.find('.b').val(blue);
        th.find('.b').parent('span').siblings('input').val(blue);

        $('input').bind('change keyup click', function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass('ch')) {
                $(this).parent('span').siblings('input').val($(this).val());
            }
            else {
                if ($(this).val() > 255) 
                    $(this).val(255);
                if ($(this).val() < 0) 
                    $(this).val(0);
                    $(this).siblings('span').find('input').val($(this).val());
            }

            r = parseInt(th.find('.r').val()).toString(16);
            if (r.length == 1) 
                r = '0' + r;

            g = parseInt(th.find('.g').val()).toString(16);
            if (g.length == 1) 
                g = '0' + g;

            b = parseInt(th.find('.b').val()).toString(16);
            if (b.length == 1) 
                b = '0' + b;

            x = r + g + b;

            th.find('.result').html(x);
            th.css('backgroundColor', '#' + x);

        });
    });
});
});
```

Comment: So "what is wrong" or "doesn't work"?

Comment: Unfortunately ya it doesn't work.

Comment: So "what is wrong" or "doesn't work"? The *problem* (e.g. errors, symptoms, expected behavior) needs to be explained. If you could summarize what "didn't work" in one line, what would it be?

Comment: The background color for the div container is supposed to change corresponding to the rgb slider values when they are changed. It used to work until I added the randomizing color function, and now I cant figure out what's wrong. It's really a two-part problem because I also need to figure out how to get the button event to line up so that it's generating colors and the sliders are working. Sorry for the lack of clarity

Comment: Any takers? I'm really stuck :/

Comment: When I run it with jSLint it's finding a lot of errors but only because it doesn't recognize HTML5 form syntax, I guess

Comment: I referenced both of the code on these pages if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/WvjJZ/11/ and http://www.codenothing.com/archives/2009/javascript-random-color-generator/

Answer (score 0):

For starters your `onclick="click()"` is un-needed, you can use jQuery's `.click()` to capture that like `$('#button').click(function(){/*do stuff*/})` or `$('#button').click(function_name)` then you have a bunch of errors in your code, [jslint](http://jslint.com) or [jshint](http://www.jshint.com/) could help, here's what errors I see:

> Error: Problem at line 51 character 51: Expected '{' and instead saw
>   'i'. if (i === undefined || typeof i !== 'number') i = 0;
>
> Problem at line 52 character 45: Expected '{' and instead saw
>   'return'. else if (i++ > defaults.recursionLimit) return
>   defaults.recursion();
>
> Problem at line 55 character 26: Expected '{' and instead saw 'hex'.
>   if (self.stack[hex]) hex = self.random(i);
>
> Problem at line 63 character 19: Expected '{' and instead saw 'hex'.
>   if (! levels) hex = self.random(i);
>
> Problem at line 74 character 1: Expected '}' to match '{' from line 2
>   and instead saw 'rgb2hex'. rgb2hex: function (r,g,b) {
>
> Problem at line 74 character 8: Missing semicolon. rgb2hex: function
>   (r,g,b) {
>
> Problem at line 74 character 8: Expected '}' to match '{' from line 1
>   and instead saw ':'. rgb2hex: function (r,g,b) {
>
> Problem at line 74 character 10: Expected ')' and instead saw
>   'function'. rgb2hex: function (r,g,b) {
>
> Problem at line 74 character 26: Missing semicolon. rgb2hex: function
>   (r,g,b) {
>
> Problem at line 74 character 27: Expected to see a statement and
>   instead saw a block. rgb2hex: function (r,g,b) {
>
> Problem at line 74 character 27: Stopping, unable to continue. (50%
>   scanned). Implied global: $ 1, r 74, g 74, b 74 Unused variable: Color
>   1 "ready"